# SSRS subscription email discards single page pdf attachment on Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, reporting-services

Single page pdf attachments are shown inline on Ipad. 
However, when an SSRS subscription sends an email with single page (pdf)attachment, Ipad does not show the attachment at all even though I can see the paper clip icon.

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: is it a browser issue? try another browsers.

Comment: no a browser issue. it seems that is just how ios handles single page attachments. and somehow the format of the email generated be ssrs subscription is not handled well